# Можно ли ботом получить айди прикрепленной к каналу группы?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

Можно ли ботом получить айди прикрепленной к каналу группы,в которой остаются комментарии? То есть той группы, которая находится тут в поле 'discussion'[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё, нашёл, у chat есть метод "linked_chat_id"

Comment: Ну напишите это в ответ, вы ведь можете отвечать на собственный вопрос.